# Is Origin required to play the digital download version of TOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Other than Origin being required to download and install the game content in the first place, is it required to *play* the digital download version of *Star Wars: The Old Republic*?  Could I literally uninstall it later?

Is it like *EVE Online* and Steam, where (if installed through Steam) the client keeps the game updated but isn't really required to play, or is it totally separate (as *EVE* can be if installed directly from CCP).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Origin application is not required for play. (Unlike most Steam games for example.)

You only need to register the CD key on your totally separate account on swtor.com and download the SWTOR launcher available there. The SWTOR launcher keeps the game up to date on it's own, for everyone whether they bought it via Origin or a retail box.

Comment: It's good that SWTOR doesn't require Origin but be careful before comparing Origin and Steam - There's a huge debate of how invasive (they both) are and no 2 people seem to agree. FWIW I personally avoid Origin at all cost because of their data collection polices - but each to their own.

Answer (score 5):

I tracked down the [official FAQ entry](http://www.swtor.com/info/faq/game#q399961) for this:

> *If I uninstall Origin will it affect my ability to play Star Wars: The Old Republic?*
>
> You can still play the Game without Origin but will lose the add-on
>   features that Origin provides.

Comment: What are these add-on features?

Comment: @NickT I wouldn't know. I just reported the official reply to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Of what I've read, I would say that the Origin activation is done trough the CD Key, which should be given to you by email somewhere around launch.

What I've read also tells me that you will mostly play apart from Origin... even heard that you could play without even origin installed.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd guess the reason for it is you don't cite or link to any credible source.

Comment: I was in the beta, and didn't need to install origin. My client has patched itself for early access, and I still don't need origin. I recall reading that I didn't need to install origin for running the game, but as all official SW-TOR forums have been wiped after the beta, I can't link to an official post. However, for those who have not been in the beta: you'll have to install origin to download the game. As dvds are not available yet, it's unknown whether that route will require origin.

Comment: @Sjoerd did you need Origin in the first place though?  As far as I know, in order to get the digital download you *must* use it at least initially.

Comment: @NickT Yes, it appears so. BTW, I tracked down an official FAQ entry - see my answer.

Comment: @NickT The beta client did not require Origin to be downloaded. That same client has patched itself and should enable me to play the real game (according to the official FAQ). So yes, I never had to install Origin. OTOH, no, that route is not available anymore for people who want to install it today.